# list of lists- recursive pairs prolog

Tags: list, prolog

how can I put all the pairs in a one list?

I have -

```
pair([H|T], [H,E]) :- member(E, T).
pair([_|T], P) :- pair(T, P).
```

and I want the answer will be a list of pairs.

so I try -

```
listPairs([],[Res1]):-
      Res1=[].
listPairs(L,[Res2]):-
    L=[H|T],
    append(pair([H|T],[Res2]),listPairs(T,[Res2])).
```

but I miss something of the lists.. 
because it is not compile.

Comment: You can't nest predicate calls that way. `pair([H|T], [Res2])` succeeds or fails. It doesn't return a value that you can pass to `append/2`. Likewise with `listPairs/2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really see what you aim to do with `append/2`. You can definitely not put goals that should be called in the `append/3` because in that case, they will be seen as functors.

You can however easily use the `findall/3` predicate which is implemented in nearly all Prolog systems (well at least all I have seen that are actively used):

```
listPairs(L,Pairs) :-
    findall(Pair,pair(L,Pair),Pairs).
```

`findall/3` works as follows:

```
findall(Format,Goal,List).
```

Here you specify a `Goal` (here `pair(L,Pair)`) and Prolog will call the `Goal`. Each time the `Goal` succeed, Prolog will suspend the interpreter and add en element formatted as `Format` to the `List`. When the `Goal` fails, the list of all `Format`s is returned.

If I run the query, I get:

```
?- listPairs([1,a,2,'5'],Pairs).
Pairs = [[1, a], [1, 2], [1, '5'], [a, 2], [a, '5'], [2, '5']].
```

Note that `L` must be grounded (as list, meaning without uninstantiated tail, an uninstantiated element is fine), since otherwise the number of `pair/2` elements that you will generate is infinite and thus you will run out of global stack (or memory in general).

Comment: SWI-Prolog has an `append/2`: "`append(+ListOfLists, ?List)` Concatenate  a list of lists.   Is true if `ListOfLists` is a  list of
    lists, and `List` is the concatenation of these lists."

Comment: Ah, that explains, but still it is applied the wrong way.